# How to exclude specified class initialize when build graalVM native image?

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm

I import a lib ,and there is a factory like this :

```java
  public static RequestExecutor<String, String> create(RequestHttp requestHttp) {
    switch (requestHttp.getRequestType()) {
      case APACHE_HTTP:
        return new ApacheSimplePostRequestExecutor(requestHttp);
      case JODD_HTTP:
        return new JoddHttpSimplePostRequestExecutor(requestHttp);
      case OK_HTTP:
        return new OkHttpSimplePostRequestExecutor(requestHttp);
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("error http type");
    }
  }
```

I use the default ApacheSimplePostRequestExecutor, the other two case code was never executed , and of couse , no JoddHttp or OkHttp dependence in my namespace .
the code work fine in jvm
but when i build for native image

```bash
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildRunner] /opt/graalvm/bin/native-image -J-Dsun.nio.ch.maxUpdateArraySize=100 -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -J-Dlogging.initial-configurator.min-level=500 -J-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxLogDelegateFactory -J-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true -J-Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -J-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=DISABLED -J-Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder=3 -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.country=US -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --features=io.quarkus.runner.Feature,io.quarkus.runtime.graal.ResourcesFeature,io.quarkus.runtime.graal.DisableLoggingFeature -J--add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -H:+CollectImageBuildStatistics -H:ImageBuildStatisticsFile=jsa2-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner-timing-stats.json -H:BuildOutputJSONFile=jsa2-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner-build-output-stats.json --initialize-at-run-time=me.chanjar.weixin.common.util.http,me.chanjar.weixin.common.util.http.okhttp.OkHttpSimplePostRequestExecutor -H:+PrintClassInitialization -H:+AllowFoldMethods -J-Djava.awt.headless=true --no-fallback --link-at-build-time -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:-AddAllCharsets --enable-url-protocols=http -H:NativeLinkerOption=-no-pie -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace -J--add-exports=org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.nativeimage.impl=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk=ALL-UNNAMED --exclude-config io\.netty\.netty-codec /META-INF/native-image/io\.netty/netty-codec/generated/handlers/reflect-config\.json --exclude-config io\.netty\.netty-handler /META-INF/native-image/io\.netty/netty-handler/generated/handlers/reflect-config\.json jsa2-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner -jar jsa2-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
```

the error is :

```java
Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved field during parsing: okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion. This error is reported at image build time because class me.chanjar.weixin.common.util.http.okhttp.OkHttpSimplePostRequestExecutor is registered for linking at image build time by command line
```

look like the native build still try to build no used  JoddHttpSimplePostRequestExecutor ,OkHttpSimplePostRequestExecutor.

Is there any way to exclude native build for the two class ?
I use --initialize-at-run-time but it to no effect .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a GraalVM substitution for this. It would looks something like:

```
import com.oracle.svm.core.annotate.Alias;
import com.oracle.svm.core.annotate.Substitute;
import com.oracle.svm.core.annotate.TargetClass;

...


@TargetClass(value = WhateverTheClassNameIs.class)
public final class WhateverTheClassNameIsSubstitutions {

  @Substitute 
  public static RequestExecutor<String, String> create(RequestHttp requestHttp) {
    switch (requestHttp.getRequestType()) {
      case APACHE_HTTP:
        return new ApacheSimplePostRequestExecutor(requestHttp);
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("error http type");
    }
  }

}
```